# Set font for single symbol back to standard in math mode

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I am trying to use the Kleene's O (`$\mathcal{O}$`) in some equations to represent a zero matrix.
However, I am using Times as my standard math font and do not like the look of the symbol and would like to set it back to the standard font.

How can I set the math font to standard for just a single symbol.
I would like to create a command permitting me to do so as such:

```
\newcommand{\zeromatrix}{\mathcal{O}}
```

How can I however set the font for the single symbol inside back to standard?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit:**
Here's a minimal working example of my document with the math font set to Times:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
    $\mathcal{O}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on this site, please post a full minimal example. You mention you are using Times as the math font, how? Also, don't use `$` inside that definition, it's being used in math more anyway so the `$` does more harm than good.

Comment: A minimal working sample is needed.

Comment: This answer is closed, but `unicode-math` lets you use `\setmathfont]range={cal,bfcal}]` option to change only `\mathcal` and `\mathbfcal`.  You’ll also want to set `scale=MatchUppercase` to make sure the letters are the right size. For example, `\setmathfont[range={cal,bfcal}, scale=MatchUppercase]{Latin Modern Math}`. Several fonts, incluing XITS Math, Stix Two Math, and Asana Math, have separate `\mathcal` and `\mathscr` that you can access with `StylisticSet` or `Alternate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the package `mathptmx` that changes style of `\mathcal`. So what you should do is back:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\DeclareSymbolFont{xsymbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{xsymbols}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcal}{xsymbols} 

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{O}$
\end{document}
```

And we have another easier way with the help of the package `mathalfa`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[cal=cm]{mathalfa}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{O}$
\end{document}
```

The standard math calligraphic O now is back:

[image]

**Note** that you can't change only the style of `\mathcal{O}` but also `\mathcal{A,B}...`, i.e., `\mathcal{A,B,C,D}...` all get back to be standard.

Comment: This is even better than what I was looking for! Great answer, Thank you very much! You nailed it even before I could post the minimum working sample! ;)

Comment: @budekatude: Beware, however, of the remarks made in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14406/69818) apropos wasting one math alphabet for a single symbol: you might prefer to use the more refined technique given in that answer.